# way to register network callback for dumping messages

Tags: c#, network-programming, fiddler, system.net

I have a C# console app that I am doing some testing of a rest api. Currently I am using fiddler to capture the calls for debugging, which is fine, however...

Is there is a way to register a callback from the network stack to dump the same information programmatically, and only for the calls the process is making.

Essentially a process specific, programmatic version of fiddler. A bonus would be capturing it before SSL encrypted it (and after it was decrypted).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [Fiddler Core API](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-demo) and see if it interests you to solve your problem. [Download](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/) it from here.

Comment: That's probably the best answer. For .NET, you can enable System.NET logging, but this dumps to an extremely verbose XML file and you'd have to write a parser to interpret it at runtime.